# iOS: How to get swipe effect between views of tabbed view controller?

Tags: ios, ipad

I keep seeing apps that appear to be tabbed view controller apps, where the user can easily swipe left or right between views.
How do I enable that kind of behavior?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The best and least hassle free solution I found is Andrey Tarantsov's ATPagingViev class. Works just like a UITableView, i.e. how many pages do you want, scroll horiz or vert. provide view for page, etc. Very easy and well coded. It's here: [SoloComponents](https://github.com/andreyvit/SoloComponents-iOS/tree/11b2d4a0b6187f231aef2499e46ad5e97571263b#readme)

It also has a recycling feature so it's memory stable.

Answer (score 3):

If you refer  to something like Apples photo app, it is using `UIScrollView` which has a property to enable paging. 
If you define the views content width wider than your view's frame, you'll get the effect you describe. The view will page in steps of it's bounds width.
On each page you can place another view.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html

Comment: But suppose you have 20 screens, each is 768 pixels wide. Won't that exceed that maximum dimensions of a UIView? I thought it could only be 2k by 2k...

Comment: In this case, don't create 20 views at once, create the visible view and the view either side of the current view. As you swipe through, you can preload the next view and unload the furthest away views.

Comment: David is right. You'll only need to screens. Or three if you want to allow the user to start in either direction.

Answer (score 1):

Another option I found is SwipeView:

https://github.com/nicklockwood/SwipeView